# I want to know how to create rooms in socket.io and store them in sessions

Tags: socket.io

I want to make multiple chatrooms like dynamic and I want to make them like this that if we refresh the page it retains the chat and users inside the rooms, I am new to socket.io and looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question so it's not really possible to be very specific with an answer.  The general steps to retaining one or more "rooms" for a given user are as follows:

1. Install a session manager on your server. `express-session` is popular and you can then pick which data store you want to use with it (there are dozens of choices).  This will give you a semi-persistent session object for each user who connects to your server.
2. When a user connects to your server for the first time, a session object and matching session cookie will be created that allows your server to identify that browser the next time it connects.
3. You can initialize a `rooms` property in that session to be an empty array or perhaps a `Set` object (which makes lookup a bit simpler for the later steps).
4. When this user gets put in a specific chat room, you add that room name to the `session.rooms` array or Set.
5. When the user leaves a specific chat room, you remove that room name from the `session.rooms` array or Set.
6. When a user re-connects, you look in their session and automatically join them to any rooms that the session says they should be connected to.
7. You probably need some sort of timeout process so that if a user remains disconnected for a certain period of time, you remove their session or at least clear their rooms list.

Comment: @faizKahn - Did this answer your question?